# Problem at marshalling a standard C++ string to a C# string

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, dllimport

I'm writing a wrapper for a DLL that manages an OCR device. The DLL has a method whose signature resembles the following:

```
unsigned long aMethod(char **firstParameter, char **secondParameter);
```

aMethod returns string pointers to all parameters.

I wrote this signature in `C#`... it is almost functional:

```
[DllImport(aDll.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static unsafe extern ulong aMethod(ref IntPtr firstParameter, 
    ref IntPtr secondParameter);
```

I do the invocation in this way:

```
aMethod(ref firstParameter, ref secondParameter);
```

Marshalling and unmarshalling related to the strings is done as here:

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(firstParameter)
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(secondParameter)
```

Obviously, this marshalling has been selected based on DLL's API conventions.

Now, the marshalling process has a problem. Suppose that the device has an input with this string "abcdefg". If I use the DLL from pure C++ code I get "abcdefg" as an output. But, if I use the C# signature I´ve wroted, the string loses its first character and looks like "bcdefg".

What´s going wrong? How can I fix the C# method?

Comment: I'm flying blind here (don't have an access to the compilers as I type this), but double-check the return type on your C# signature.

You have it as `ulong`, which is 64-bit.  The C method signature is `unsigned long`.  The size varies by architecture, but with Visual C++, `unsigned long` is 32-bit.  I don't see how this would cause the  problem you're asking about, but it is one more thing to check and make sure you have correct.

Comment: Done SwDevMan81! write it as an answer and I will give you the check!

Comment: @Juan - Ok, I added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the [`CharSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx) to `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those parameters are given to you from the application, why not simply use:

```
[DllImport(aDll.dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static unsafe extern uint aMethod(out string firstParameter, 
    out string secondParameter);
```

If you want them to go both ways, you could use a `ref StringBuilder` with a pre-allocated size (you should also use this if the C function expects you to manage your own memory -- you didn't say).