# Which configuration do I need to use an external DLL in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, interop, oracle11g, dllimport

I'm working with an external DLL to consume an OCR device using a wrapper written by me. I have made tests on the wrapper and it works perfectly. But, when I use a WinForms project to consume the client class of the wrapper (located an another project), an error arises when calling C# methods imported from the DLL (using `[DLLImport(...)]`) saying that the DLL is not registered.

The error says:

> "DLL Library function no found. Check registry install path."

All executions have been made in debug mode.
I've compared both projects configuration. The most relevant difference is that Test project is oriented to Any CPU and WinForms app only points to x86.

What could it be?

**Updates**

1. I've tried to register the dll using `Regsvr32.exe` but it didn't work. I thought about using `Gacutil.exe` but it required to uninstall all frameworks beyond .net framework 1.1...
2. I was wondering... at testing environment probably everything works well because testing framework has its dll's or executable files (or something like that) totally registered in windows, so those are trusted dlls. It is possible that debug generated dlls are not trusted by windows and therefore this problem arises?
3. I've created a form in the same troubling project and then I call the OCRWrapper from a button I've added to it. The OCR's worked!!. Unfortunately, it is difficult to rewrite the first form because we  have invested a lot of hours in it; so, I'm still wondering what do I need to change in the troubling form...
4. I started again the form's development from scratch and added all the components related to it; everything worked well, the OCR read succesfully all data. When I loaded a combo box using a call to an `ObjectContext` and the error appeared again... I'm using an entity framework connected to Oracle.

Comment: Are you running on a 64 bit system?

Comment: @StuartDunkeld Intel core 2 duo... I suppose it is a 64 bit system, but, although I have googled it, I'm not after all sure...

Comment: @HansPassant the exception doesn't come from Visual Studio... when I call a method from de OCR (using a `[DLLImport]` marked method), the error message returned is `"DLL Library function no found. Check registry install path."`.

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras - It sounds like your application cannot find the file in question.  You need to determine if the operating system on your machine is x86 or x64.

Comment: @Ramhound As I've said, when debugging test project the DLL does not complain... it works...

Comment: @HansPassant I created a new WinForms project, inside it I called the wrapper and the OCR worked well. I copied all forms from the old project to the new one and then the DLL failed... that's why I think it is not OCR's DLL problem...

Comment: @HansPassant could the project be corrupt?

Comment: @HansPassant :) the software you are talking about is made by one of the biggest hardware-of-its-kind factory in the whole world. Actually, I didn't translate the message from spanish; it is in its own english :) . But, I've to recognize that this piece of code has a  weak documentation. Sometimes I become amazed about the quality of the products made by big enterprises; may be it is easy to get big without have product quality in mind.

Comment: Did you change the name of the DLL that you're importing?

Comment: Have you tried copying all the form from the old project to the new one, one by one, to check which form is making it fail? Also, do you have any other external dependencies?

Comment: @rodrigo yes... it was funny. I created a new winforms project and test to call the method from a component. It worked, so I created a new winform project (different from any other) and began to copy-paste the old forms to the new ones. Also, I created a new resources folder and a resx file. When I debugged the new project, it didn't work. The project is more or less immature... but I didn't try to copy and test that functionality form by form...

Comment: @DonAndre Nope... as I've said, I used a privative dll. I didn't change it's name. I've made many copies of that dll, and I also tested functionality against the dll installed by the OCR's installed.

Comment: @HansPassant Please look at third update....

Comment: @rodrigo Please look at third update....

Comment: @HansPassant please look at fourth update

Comment: @rodrigo please look at fourth update

Comment: Does it fail just by compiling/linking the `ObjectContext` code, even if it is not executed? Or does it fail only if that code is executed before calling DLL?

Comment: @rodrigo fails only before an EF's API instruction is called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a theory.

Let's imagine the following situation:

- The ocr.dll depends on some other native DLL, lets call it *other.dll [A]*.

  - In case this is a static dependency, you'll see it through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
  - If its dynamic, you can use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to monitor DLL loading in your working test project at run-time.
- Your ADO.NET provider uses native DLLs under the hood (this is certainly true for ODP.NET) which depend on *other.dll [B]*, which happens to have the same name but is actually a different DLL (or at least a different version) compared to *other.dll [A]*.

Then, in run-time, this might happen:

- When you connect to the database, ADO.NET provider dynamically loads its native DLLs, including the *other.dll [B]*.
- Then you try to call a function from OCR DLL. The P/Invoke tries to load the OCR DLL dynamically and succeeds, but the *other.dll [B]* is already loaded and ocr.dll tries to use some function **from it**, instead from *other.dll [A]* where it actually exists.

Welcome to DLL hell. So what can you do?

- Try varying the order of calls to ocr.dll and ADO.NET provider to see anything changes. If you are (very) lucky, *other.dll [A]* might actually be a newer version that is still backward-compatible with *other.dll [B]* and things migh magically start to work.
- Try another version of ADO.NET provider.
- Try another ADO.NET provider.
- Try getting a statically-linked ocr.dll from your vendor (i.e. no run-time dependency on *other.dll [A]*).

Answer (score 0):

So, the call to the DLL works from a single button, but it does not work from a complex form. I'd say that there is an undefined behavior going on. The question remains whether it is you, that wrote the marshalling incorrectly, or it the DLL that is badly written.

Since we do not have access to the source code of the DLL, maybe you can post the prototype of the function, and all relevant struct definitions, and the DllImport line that you wrote for it?

Comment: I don't think that the error lays at marshalling because it OCR fails _only_ when called from a specific form... but take a look: `[DllImport("aDll.dll")] private static extern uint aMethod()`,  `[DllImport("aDll.dll",  CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] private static extern string aMethod2(ulong aParameter);`, `[DllImport("aDll.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`
, `private static unsafe extern ulong aMethod3(ref IntPtr aParameter, ref IntPtr anotherParameter, ref IntPtr afterTheLastParameter);`.

Comment: Sice I'm working with a privative dll for a security business I'm not allowed to reveal specific details. But signatures are _like_ the ones I've wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515798/problem-at-marshalling-a-standard-c-string-to-a-c-string), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423376/how-can-i-write-a-signature-on-c-for-a-wrapped-c-method-having-double-indirect) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410382/how-can-i-write-a-signature-on-c-for-a-wrapped-c-method-having-a-pointer-to-a)

Comment: What you are doing is tricky... I've just seen the other SO questions and I'm not so sure that they are totally right. I'd need to see the C prototypes of these functions, and maybe some sample C code using them. The prototype is not always enough to write a proper marshall, you need behavior information.

Answer (score 0):

Google can't find that error message which means(not definitely though :)) it is not a system message but a custom one coming from the code in the dll. So the dll does something dodgy. I guess it tries to double dispatch your call to another function internally.

Few things I suggest you try:

- Run a x86 configuration. In the project properties -> Build tab set the platform to x86. this is assuming the dll is an x86 dll.

  dumpbin /headers orc.dll

  ```
      File Type: DLL
      FILE HEADER VALUES

                   14C machine (**x86**)
                     4 number of sections
              4CE7B6FC time date stamp Sat Nov 20 11:54:36 2010
                     0 file pointer to symbol table
                     0 number of symbols
                    E0 size of optional header
                  2102 characteristics
                         Executable
                         32 bit word machine
                         DLL
  ```

This command line should tell you the bitness. In case it is a 64 bit run a 64 bit config instead but I bet it is 32 bit.

- Do not include the dll in the project. I guess you do that already. Make sure the dll is in a folder that is in the %PATH% environment variable. When you run this at command prompt:

where ocr.dll

should tell you where the dll is. If it doesn't add the folder where the dll is installed to the %PATH%.